# When using @run_on_executor in tornado, the error is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'

Tags: tornado

I am executing the write_message method of websocket in the handler, I will report an error.

```py
class Test_Handler(BaseHandler):

    @run_on_executor
    def get(self):
        host_name = 'Win10'
        ws = WebSocketHandler.clients[host_name]['self']
        ws.write_message(json.dumps({
            'status': 203,  # 状态201是为启动机器人
        }))
        return self.write({'status': 200})
```

```py
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 256, in write_message
    return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 801, in write_message
    fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 780, in _write_frame
    return self.stream.write(frame)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 536, in write
    future = Future()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 694, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 602, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not call any Tornado methods (except `IOLoop.add_callback`) from another thread. This includes the threads created by executors. Use executors when calling synchronous code; they're not needed for async code that is written for Tornado, and I see no reason to use one in this snippet.

In general, it's preferred to use `IOLoop.run_in_executor` instead of the `@run_on_executor` decorator, because it makes the transitions between async and sync modes more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class `Test_Handler` contains two members:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.executor = tornado.concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(...)
    self.io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
```